# HoloEverywhere Eclipse Install

Tags: eclipse, adt, android-holo-everywhere

I am trying to use HoloEverywhere and can't figure out how to install it. I have followed what was listed on [this](https://github.com/ChristopheVersieux/HoloEverywhere) GitHub page. I just get a lot of errors. Does anyone know how to get this to work with android 2.3.3 API 10? I am running Android Developer Tools Build: v21.1.0-569685

Answer (score 1):

Just update your Eclipse ADT and Android SDK and follow this steps

1. Enter to https://github.com/Prototik/HoloEverywhere
2. Click Download ZIP
3. Decompress file downloaded
4. Open ADT
5. Select File > Import > Android > Existing Android Code Into
   Workspace > Next
6. On Root Directory click Browse... and search for folder created in step 3
7. Open that folder and select library folder, then click Open
8. Then click Finish and wait until it load
9. Right click your existing project and select Properties > Android >
   click Add...
10. Select HoloEverywhere Library and click OK, click OK on properties
     window

Comment: Thanks, mate.. I've been looking for something simple like this for an hour or so. :P

Answer (score 0):

Hey just try this:(giving many answers as there may be one working for you):-

```
      android:theme=“@style/Theme.Holo
               // or if you want to use the Holo light theme:
      android:theme=“@style/Theme.Holo.Light
```

also this:

```
  Theme.Holo and Theme.Holo.Light have been available since API level 11, but Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar is new in API level 14.


      res/values/themes.xml:

                <resources>
                     <style name="MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme">
               <!-- Any customizations for your app running on pre-3.0 devices here -->
               </style>
               </resources>


      res/values-v11/themes.xml:

                  <resources>
                       <style name="MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo">
                         <!-- Any customizations for your app running on devices with Theme.Holo here -->
                        </style>
                        </resources>



              Finally, in AndroidManifest.xml:


                          <!-- [...] -->
                 <application android:name="MyApplication"
                       android:label="@string/application_label"
                       android:icon="@drawable/app_icon"
                       android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
                        android:theme="@style/MyTheme">
                           <!-- [...] -->
```

and in activity:

```
             <activity
                  android:name=".login"
                 android:label="@string/login"
                android:noHistory="true"
                  android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light"/>

              <activity
                android:name=".Preferences"
                    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light" >
```